# I am having trouble finding honey

Tags: terraria

Ive been looking in the jungle and I am having difficulty finding honey. Any tips?

Comment: Just keep lookin, you'll only find it in beehives so don't expect it to just 'be there'. Look for the yellow beehive blocks

Answer (score 7):

Well, apart from cheating (i.e. using a [map viewer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Map_viewers)), the only thing you can do is explore the underground jungle cave by cave until you find a bee hive.

What might speed this up a little is using the light effects of the [Dark Lance](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dark_Lance) or [Gungnir](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gungnir) to more quickly see what's behind walls.